# Developer Program

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I created an iPhone app on a computer and installed it on an iPhone at home.

Being currently abroad, is it possible to use the same developer program on a different mac and install the same app on a differetn iPhone?

Comment: Why do you still refuse to accept answers although many people told you already that this is how a great part of SO works?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I dont think it matters... all the best!

Answer (score 0):

yes you can..add your new iphone udid in the ios provisioning portal  and get the new(old provisioning with newly added udid) provisioning then drop into your xcode.make sure you have to place your developer certificate also.